# CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu; fails despite postgresql-plperl-12 being installed

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, plperl

I'm on an Ubuntu-derived system (specifically pop_os from System76). I am trying to get Bucardo installed, but it appears to be failing because `plperlu` is not functional.

In a `psql` prompt:

```
# CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plperl": No such file or directory
```

However, running:

```
$ pg_config --pkglibdir
/usr/lib/postgresql/12/lib
```

and:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/postgresql/12/lib/plperl*
/usr/lib/postgresql/12/lib/plperl.so
```

I do have the `postgresql-plperl-12` package installed:

```
# apt install postgresql-plperl-12
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-plperl-12 is already the newest version (12.7-0ubuntu0.20.10.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
```

All the related errors I could find related either to the relevant package not being installed or the language not being created in postgres, so I'm a little stymied. The `CREATE LANGUAGE` statement's error appears to indicate that Postgres is looking for a file without an extension, but I'm not sure if that's fixable by a simple `mv`, and if so, who to report a package bug to.

---

Edit:
Prompted by @AdrianKlaver's comment:

```
# CREATE EXTENSION plperlu;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/plperlu.control": No such file or directory
```

... now why is it looking in /usr/share/postgresql/**10**/?
I may be misinterpreting, but I have:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.7 (Ubuntu 12.7-0ubuntu0.20.10.1)
```

`plperlu.control` does exist in `/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/`... but `SELECT version()` is indeed PostgreSQL 10.10... so something somewhere has gone wrong during an update. Does having a `psql` version that differs from the actualy postgres that is running cause issues?

Comment: Sounds like you installed PostgreSQL and PL/Perl from different packagers.

Comment: Have you tried `CREATE EXTENSION plperlu;`? As languages are packaged as extensions now.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe both are from the package manager

Comment: The Debian/Ubuntu packaging will use the latest version of `psql` by default. To see what Postgres server version you are connecting to, in `psql` do `select version();` Also to see what servers you have running do `pg_lsclusters` at the command line.

Comment: So to be clear the server version you are connecting to is Postgres 10, correct? If so why not just install `postgresql-plperl-10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that there are multiple versions of Postgres running as servers. Running `pg_lsclusters` will show what they are. The `CREATE EXTENSION` fails as the extension code for the version of Postgres that the command is being run on has not been installed.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem on Debian 11 and Postgres 12. Solution that worked for me:

```
apt update
apt install -y postgresql-server-dev-12 wget
wget https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgresql-12/postgresql-plperl-12_12.10-1.pgdg20.04+1+b1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i ./postgresql-plperl-12_12.10-1.pgdg20.04+1+b1_amd64.deb
apt --fix-broken install # because problems on dpkg command
apt list --installed | grep postgresql-plperl-12
```